# Stratifying a density plot by different groups using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, categories, density-plot

I have a data frame in R called `x` that has hundreds of rows. Each row is a person. I have two variables, `Height`, which is continuous, and `Country`, which is a factor. I want to plot a smoothed histogram of all of the heights of the individuals. I want to stratify it by `Country`. I know that I can do that with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x, aes(x=Height, colour = (Country == "USA"))) + geom_density()
```

This plots everyone from the USA as one color (true) and everyone from any other country as the other color (false). However, what I would really like to do is plot everyone from the USA in one color and everyone from Oman, Nigeria, and Switzerland as the other color. How would I adapt my code to do this?

Comment: You could try creating a column in `x` which will be something like: `country2 <- ifelse(x$Country == "USA", "color1", ifelse(x$Country %in% c("Oman", "Nigeria", "Switzerland"), "color2", "")`. Then use that column as colour.

Comment: As I understand you want one density for ach country and one colour for USA and another one for the othter, right ? then add **group = Country** in the aes function.

Comment: @PeterDee What if I wanted to plot two completely different smoothed histograms on the same plot? Is there a way just to plot the first, leave it on the screen, and then overlay the other in a different color?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean - comment based on the plots below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made up some data for illustration:

```
head(iris)
table(iris$Species)
df <- iris
df$Species2 <- ifelse(df$Species == "setosa", "blue", 
               ifelse(df$Species == "virginica", "red", ""))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length, colour = (Species == "setosa")))
p + geom_density() # Your example
```

[image: example with true and false]

```
# Now let's choose the other created column
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length, colour = Species2))
p + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~Species2)
```

[image: example with extra column]
**Edit** to get rid of the "countries" that you don't want in the plot, just subset them out of the data frame you use in the plot (note that the labels with the colours don't exactly match but that can be changed within the data frame itself):

```
p <- ggplot(df[df$Species2 %in% c("blue", "red"),], aes(x = Sepal.Length, colour = Species2))
p + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~Species2)
```

[image: example with filtered data frame]
And to overlay the lines just take out the `facet_wrap`:

```
p + geom_density()
```

[image: example without facet_wrap]

Comment: What if I want to overlay the green and the blue lines on the same plot? And eliminate the red line entirely? (Referring to the colors of the lines themselves)

Answer (score 0):

I enjoyed working through the excellent answer above. Here are my mods.

```
df <- iris
df$Species2 <- ifelse(df$Species == "setosa", "blue", 
           ifelse(df$Species == "virginica", "red", ""))
homes2006 <- df

names(homes2006)[names(homes2006)=="Species"] <- "ownership"
homes2006a <- as.data.frame(sapply(homes2006, gsub, 
                               pattern ="setosa",                                         replacement = "renters"))
homes2006b <- as.data.frame(sapply(homes2006a, gsub,                                       pattern = "virginica", 
                        replacement = "home-owners"))
homes2006c <- as.data.frame(sapply(homes2006b, gsub,                                       pattern = "versicolor", 
                        replacement = "home-owners"))

##somehow sepal-length became a factor column
homes2006c[,1] <- as.numeric(homes2006c[,1])

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(homes2006c, aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
           colour = (ownership == "home-owners")))

p + ylab("number of households") +
xlab("monthly income (NIS)") +
ggtitle("income distribution by home ownership") +
geom_density()
```

[image]